# How to upload a CSV or .sql file to Datastore (Google App Engine)

Tags: csv, google-cloud-datastore, bulkinsert

I have looked here on stack overflow from some links about uploading a CSV file to datastore, but I could not found any solutions that fit our needs.

I would like to know if there is a possibility to make a bulk insert from a CSV or .sql to a datastore on a specific ndb model and how to do it.

I read something informing that ndb does not support bulkloader, is that true?
Could you provide us some step by step or examples using python to do so?

Thanks

Comment: I'm also noticing a complete lack of documentation on how to get bulk data into datastore.